# How to run rule even when some of its inputs are missing?

Tags: snakemake

In the first step of my process, I am extracting some hourly data from a database. Because of things data is sometimes missing for some hours resulting in files. As long as the amount of missing files is not too large I still want to run some of the rules that depend on that data. When running those rules I will check how much data is missing and then decide if I want to generate an error or not.

An example below. The `Snakefile`:

```
rule parse_data:
    input:
       "data/1.csv", "data/2.csv", "data/3.csv", "data/4.csv"
    output:
       "result.csv"
    shell:
       "touch {output}"


rule get_data: 
    output:
        "data/{id}.csv"
    shell:
        "Rscript get_data.R {output}"
```

And my `get_data.R` script:

```
output <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1]

if (output == "data/1.csv") 
  stop("Some error")
writeLines("foo", output)
```

How do I force running of the rule `parse_data` even when some of it's inputs are missing? I do not want to force running any other rules when input is missing.

One possible solution would be to generate, for example, an empty file in `get_data.R` when the query failed. However, in practice I am also using `--restart-times 5` when running `snakemake` as the query can also fail because of database timeouts. When creating an empty file this mechanism of retrying the queries would no longer work.

Answer (score 2):

You need [data-dependent conditional execution](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution).

Use a checkpoint on `get_data`. Then you replace `parse_data`'s input with a function, that aggregates whatever files do exist.

(note that I am a Snakemake newbie and am just learning this myself, I hope this is helpful)

Comment: I have to parse the documentation of that feature, but it might indeed be able to do what I want. Thanks. However, it is not completely trivial. If this is the way, I might decide to rewrite my `get_data.R` to try the database a couple of times and write an empty file when that fails.